# read Xml into ms sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I want to read the xml pasted below into sql. I tried several ways from the web to parse this xml without success. 
I tried the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ejemplo2](
[RutEmisor][nvarchar](12) null,
[RutEnvia][nvarchar](12) null,
[RutReceptor][nvarchar](12) null,
[FchResol][nvarchar](12) null,
[NroResol][nvarchar](12) null
)
GO

DECLARE @messagebody XML

SELECT @messagebody = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Ejemplo.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS X

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ejemplo2]
select  a.value(N'(./RutEmisor)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutEmisor],
    a.value(N'(./RutEnvia)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutEnvia],
    a.value(N'(./RutReceptor)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutReceptor],
    a.value(N'(./FchResol)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [FchResol],
    a.value(N'(./NroResol)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [NroResol]
from @messagebody.nodes('/EnvioDTE/SetDTE/Caratula') as r(a);


Select * from dbo.Ejemplo2
```

But I get 0 rows
I tried with more simple examples and always return the data, but in this case I can't figure whats is wrong.
Any help on this will be appreciated.

The xml follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd" version="1.0">
<SetDTE ID="SetDoc">
  <TmstFirmaEnv>2003-10-13T09:33:22</TmstFirmaEnv>
 <Caratula version="1.0">
  <RutEmisor>97975000-5</RutEmisor>
  <RutEnvia>7880442-4</RutEnvia>
  <RutReceptor>60803000-K</RutReceptor>
  <FchResol>2003-09-02</FchResol>
  <NroResol>0</NroResol>
  <SubTotDTE>
   <TpoDTE>33</TpoDTE>
   <NroDTE>1</NroDTE>
  </SubTotDTE>
 </Caratula>
<DTE version="1.0">
    <Documento ID="F60T33">
        <Encabezado>
            <IdDoc>
                <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
                <Folio>60</Folio>
                <FchEmis>2003-10-13</FchEmis>
            </IdDoc>
            <Emisor>
                <RUTEmisor>97975000-5</RUTEmisor>
                <RznSoc>RUT DE PRUEBA</RznSoc>
                <GiroEmis>Insumos de Computacion</GiroEmis>
                <Acteco>31341</Acteco>
                <CdgSIISucur>1234</CdgSIISucur>
                <DirOrigen>Teatinos 120, Piso 4</DirOrigen>
                <CmnaOrigen>Santiago</CmnaOrigen>
                <CiudadOrigen>Santiago</CiudadOrigen>
            </Emisor>
            <Receptor>
                <RUTRecep>77777777-7</RUTRecep>
                <RznSocRecep>EMPRESA  LTDA</RznSocRecep>
                <GiroRecep>COMPUTACION</GiroRecep>
                <DirRecep>SAN DIEGO 2222</DirRecep>
                <CmnaRecep>LA FLORIDA</CmnaRecep>
                <CiudadRecep>SANTIAGO</CiudadRecep>
            </Receptor>
            <Totales>
                <MntNeto>100000</MntNeto>
                <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>
                <IVA>19000</IVA>
                <MntTotal>119000</MntTotal>
            </Totales>
        </Encabezado>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>011</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Parlantes Multimedia 180W.</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>20</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>4500</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>90000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>2</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>0231</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Mouse Inalambrico PS/2</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>1</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>5000</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>5000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>3</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>1515</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Caja de Diskettes 10 Unidades</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>5</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>1000</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>5000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
        <TED version="1.0">
            <DD>
                <RE>97975000-5</RE>
                <TD>33</TD>
                <F>60</F>
                <FE>2003-10-13</FE>
                <RR>77777777-7</RR>
                <RSR>EMPRESA  LTDA</RSR>
                <MNT>119000</MNT>
                <IT1>Parlantes Multimedia 180W.</IT1>
                <CAF version="1.0">
                    <DA>
                        <RE>97975000-5</RE>
                        <RS>RUT DE PRUEBA</RS>
                        <TD>33</TD>
                        <RNG>
                            <D>1</D>
                            <H>200</H>
                        </RNG>
                        <FA>2003-09-04</FA>
                        <RSAPK>
                            <M>0a4O6Kbx8Qj3K4iWSP4w7KneZYeJ+g/prihYtIEolKt3cykSxl1zO8vSXu397QhTmsX7SBEudTUx++2zDXBhZw==</M>
                            <E>Aw==</E>
                        </RSAPK>
                        <IDK>100</IDK>
                    </DA>
                    <FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">g1AQX0sy8NJugX52k2hTJEZAE9Cuul6pqYBdFxj1N17umW7zG/hAavCALKByHzdYAfZ3LhGTXCai5zNxOo4lDQ==</FRMA>
                </CAF>
                <TSTED>2003-10-13T09:33:20</TSTED>
            </DD>
            <FRMT algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">GbmDcS9e/jVC2LsLIe1iRV12Bf6lxsILtbQiCkh6mbjckFCJ7fj/kakFTS06Jo8i
S4HXvJj3oYZuey53Krniew==</FRMT>
        </TED>
        <TmstFirma>2003-10-13T09:33:20</TmstFirma>
    </Documento>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#F60T33">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>hlmQtu/AyjUjTDhM3852wvRCr8w=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>JG1Ig0pvSIH85kIKGRZUjkyX6CNaY08Y94j4UegTgDe8+wl61GzqjdR1rfOK9BGn93AMOo6aiAgolW0k/XklNVtM/ZzpNNS3d/fYVa1q509mAMSXbelxSM3bjoa7H6Wzd/mV1PpQ8zK5gw7mgMMP4IKxHyS92G81GEguSmzcQmA=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
tNEknkb1kHiD1OOAWlLKkcH/UP5UGa6V6MYso++JB+vYMg2OXFROAF7G8BNFFPQx
iuS/7y1azZljN2xq+bW3bAou1bW2ij7fxSXWTJYFZMAyndbLyGHM1e3nVmwpgEpx
BHhZzPvwLb55st1wceuKjs2Ontb13J33sUb7bbJMWh0=
</Modulus>
<Exponent>
AQAB
</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>MIIEgjCCA+ugAwIBAgIEAQAApzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtTELMAkGA1UEBhMC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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></DTE>
</SetDTE><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#SetDoc">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>4OTWXyRl5fw3htjTyZXQtYEsC3E=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>sBnr8Yq14vVAcrN/pKLD/BrqUFczKMW3y1t3JOrdsxhhq6IxvS13SgyMXbIN/T9ciRaFgNabs3pi732XhcpeiSmD1ktzbRctEbSIszYkFJY49k0eB+TVzq3eVaQr4INrymfuOnWj78BZcwKuXvDy4iAcx6/TBbAAkPFwMP9ql2s=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
tNEknkb1kHiD1OOAWlLKkcH/UP5UGa6V6MYso++JB+vYMg2OXFROAF7G8BNFFPQx
iuS/7y1azZljN2xq+bW3bAou1bW2ij7fxSXWTJYFZMAyndbLyGHM1e3nVmwpgEpx
BHhZzPvwLb55st1wceuKjs2Ontb13J33sUb7bbJMWh0=
</Modulus>
<Exponent>
AQAB
</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>MIIEgjCCA+ugAwIBAgIEAQAApzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtTELMAkGA1UEBhMC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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></EnvioDTE>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all the answers. I almost have all the XML with R!

Comment: It is very kind of you to say *Thanks a lot to all the answers* but please allow me one hint: I found this by chance... If you comment below the answer there's an alert, but your *Thank you* is not heard... Anyway, since you've crossed the 15 rep points border yourself, you are asked to vote on contributions. Vote good things up (that is the SO way to say thank you) and maybe bad things down. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works. You add "*:" for the nodes.

```
DECLARE @messagebody XML

SELECT @messagebody = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Ejemplo.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS X

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@messagebody)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ejemplo24]
select  a.value(N'(./*:RutEmisor)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutEmisor],
    a.value(N'(./*:RutEnvia)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutEnvia],
    a.value(N'(./*:RutReceptor)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutReceptor],
    a.value(N'(./*:FchResol)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [FchResol],
    a.value(N'(./*:NroResol)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [NroResol]
from @messagebody.nodes('/*:EnvioDTE/*:SetDTE/*:Caratula') as r(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is great, but you must specify the default namespace `xmlns`

Try like this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ejemplo2]
select  a.value(N'(./RutEmisor)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutEmisor],
    a.value(N'(./RutEnvia)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutEnvia],
    a.value(N'(./RutReceptor)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [RutReceptor],
    a.value(N'(./FchResol)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [FchResol],
    a.value(N'(./NroResol)[1]', N'nvarchar(12)') as [NroResol]
from @messagebody.nodes('/EnvioDTE/SetDTE/Caratula') as r(a);
```